# Duplicate resource type 3 name 1 when adding an application icon

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi 7 when I try to add a application icon (project->options->application), it says "Duplicate resource type 3 name 1". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows resources of a specific type, must have unique names. The error message is simply telling you that you have two resources of type 3 that share the same name. The solution is to locate the duplicates, and change the name of one of them. Or remove one of them.

Resource type 3 is [`RT_ICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009.aspx). So it would appear that you have two icons that share the same name. Apparently, according to the compiler, that name is `1`.

Comment: How do I locate and change the name of resources?

Comment: They are linked with `{$R resfilename.res}` or `{$RESOURCE resfilename.res}`

Comment: To expand on David's comment, if you search your entire project for $R compiler directives, you should find the names of all resources.